# KQl Subtracting over result set

Tags: kql

Using KQL. I have following log lines on daily basis in insights:

```
The SERVICE 1 reports 23253466 agreements at "2022-09-26".
The SERVICE 2 reports 23253670 agreements at "2022-09-26".
The SERVICE 1 reports 23253366 agreements at "2022-09-27".
The SERVICE 2 reports 23253575 agreements at "2022-09-27".
```

I would like results table like this:

```
  Day 1 | expected agreements (service 1) | Difference service 1 amount - service 2 amount 
  Day 2 | expected agreements (service 1) | Difference service 1 amount - service 2 amount
```

Resulting in:

```
2022-09-26 | 23253466 | -204
2022-09-27 | 23253366 | -209
```

Im already able to extract the amounts:

```
Day 1 | Service 1 | 23253466 
Day 1 | Service 2 | 23253670 
Day 2 | Service 1 | 23253366 
Day 2 | Service 2 | 23253575
```

However im unable to do the subtract over this set. So on each day: Service 1 - Service 2

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(log:string)
[
    'The SERVICE 1 reports 23253466 agreements at "2022-09-26".'
   ,'The SERVICE 2 reports 23253670 agreements at "2022-09-26".'
   ,'The SERVICE 1 reports 23253366 agreements at "2022-09-27".'
   ,'The SERVICE 2 reports 23253575 agreements at "2022-09-27".'
]    
| parse log with 'The SERVICE ' service:int ' reports ' amount:decimal ' agreements at "' day:datetime '".'
| summarize service_1 = sumif(amount, service == 1), diff = sum(iff(service == 1, 1, -1) * amount) by day
```

| day | service_1 | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-26T00:00:00Z | 23253466 | -204 |
| 2022-09-27T00:00:00Z | 23253366 | -209 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WQz2uDMBzF74L/w6OX6NChcSoVPJUedt3GLmOMtH61AaMlphsd/eMX2wlzh/1IckjeN3ze41XC2L1pyWv7phiMll3ju86T68Au9rAj3K/vHm9Xa8TQtO+1GcATniY3WQbRaCJFndWEwYJHnIfRMuTZ4pqdCcGMwOeELI/+S/iWIfkhQ/6nDGme/kJ4HotwnRP2Qg8EWxPepNnNu2EYSL/KLRWyM/Y1eTAI1R86U1S0lUq0ozB3Y6jEsaiEISMVgZ09TxgOSgkt32kCv8QoR1XW3gUZTBOUJWI/QCXr+vLHszfv6zQYTxj7uPrM42NzHI0/APZtGpn/AQAA)

Comment: I learnt a lot about `kql` (i'm an almost-noob) just by scrutinizing your snippet above. Well done!